# Honda tutu del moto - Words which say something

Tags: riddle, wordplay, computer-puzzle, imgur-maze

You find a paper lying on the sand. Does it mean something ... an imgur maze, maybe ?

> *Cultures* *reserve* *glasses*. *Twin* *economist*s *migrate*s with *tail*s in a *fine risk*. Conglomerate ... voo dun saga waga 1808 jpeg ?
>
> The *method* with *laser* generates an *charm* *impulse* in the *jail* (It's *implicit*ly obvious, right ?). There's an *economic*ally optimal *mug* in *sight* ..
>
> **Scot-free** pzihx
>
> **Back to Square One** OsGyI
>
> **Money Doesn't Grow On Trees** LPMhV
>
> **Long In The Tooth** vEcDB
>
> **Down And Out** clyFJ

You turn the page, there's something else written with a picture

> 26:34. Kill Halleigh Sinclair. In and 0ut.
>
> [image: Put the atonement cover on the ark of the covenant law in the Most Holy Place]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Puzzling.SE! Take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about this site and earn yourself your first badge. This looks like a very fine puzzle, congrats!

Comment: This puzzle doesn't ask a question. There are no clues and no activity from the brand-new user that uploaded it 5 months ago. Is it even genuine?